# List of all escape characters as they are displayed in vim

Tags: vimrc

Is there a listing of the various escape codes and how they are represented in vim (and outside I suppose to)? For example:

```
^M    -- newline
^@    -- NIL
etc.
```

It seems I always have trouble googling these to figure out what a particular code means (in this case, `^J`).

Comment: [bestasciitable.com](http://bestasciitable.com)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble sure but that doesn't really show the 'display' I am looking for -- i.e., `\r` being shown as `^J`, or maybe I'm not reading it correctly?

Comment: Well, `^J` is actually `LF` (line-feed), which C-style escapes represent as `\n`. Similarly, `^M` is actually `CR` (carriage-return), which is often seen as `\r`. So, 3 different notations. And it's easy to see by reading across two columns from J or M or @

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I see, got it, thanks for the clarification! Why is the representation done `+64` over what the code is -- i.e., NUL is 0, but represented as 64 --> @ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The man page for [ascii(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html) helps.

While it doesn't list the combinations such as `^@` and `^J`, it lists `@` and the uppercase letters, then `[`, `\`, `]`, `^` and `_`, on the right column, aligned with the control symbols on the left column.

The former (`@`, uppercase letters and the other 5 symbols) have ASCII codes `0x40` through `0x5f`, while the control characters have ASCII codes `0x00` through `0x1f`. The Control key masks bit `0x40`, so the end result of using it with those letters on the right is the corresponding control character on the left.

(The Control key also masks bit `0x20`, which explains why lowercase characters, which are on the `0x60` through `0x7f` range also produce the same control characters. `0x40 | 0x20 = 0x60` so that's what gets masked.)

In specific, `^J` is NL, newline, also represented as `"\n"`. It is the character used to indicate the end of a line in Unix file format.

Comment: oh that's great, thank you. So it seems `^M` is `\r` and `^J` is `\n`. Finally, what's the convention of using `^` as a prefix for those characters, do you know why that is done in vim?

Comment: @David542 Exactly! Updated the answer to include it in specific.

Comment: actually, one question about this. Why is `J` being used (0x4A) instead of `\n` (0x0A) for this? ie., it seems like they are adding `0x40` (64) to the original hex code for its display? Here's an image: https://imgur.com/a/Wy9WQc2.

Comment: @David542 I mixed up on my answer... Just updated it. Yes, `^J` is `"\n"` and not `"\r"`.

Comment: out of curiosity, why does it do: `The Control key masks bit 0x40, so the end result of using it with those letters on the right is the corresponding control character on the left.` so that it doesn't display the character basically "as-is", ie `NUL` for null.

Comment: @David542 NUL is not really how ASCII `0x00` is displayed... (Same with NL, CR, etc.) The names are mostly mnemonics and I'm not really aware of software that would use them for display... The normal display (in Vim, in the console, `cat -v` etc.) is to use `^<letter>`.